# Copy Constructor: Special Case

Tags: java, constructor, copy, clone

So I need to copy an instance for a method and must return an instance.

My issue is that this object consists of an array and need to copy everything in this array as well.

The class constructor only specifies the width and height of the 2d array and this class constructor cannot be altered.

How can I create a copy? The following I assume won't work because it only copies the size of array right?

```
public Grid copyGrid (Grid grid) {
        return new Grid(height, width);
    }
```

Comment: can you provide the class that you are talking about?

Comment: You need to copy the elements yourself, using a couple of nested loops.

Comment: I can't paste any code because this is a task and it is complete except for this part here. But there are several setX and setY methods

Comment: Ok, the `Grid` class has getter/setter for the array that you are talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to copy the elements yourself.

```
public Grid copyGrid (Grid grid) {
  Grid newGrid = new Grid(height, width);
  for (int row = 0; row < height; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < width; col++) {
      newGrid.getArray()[row][col] = grid.getArray()[row][col];
    }
  }
  return newGrid;
}
```

Comment: @hoya21: No this is syntactically correct, yours wasn't. And also better expresses the idea.

Comment: @hoya21 You were treating the `Grid` class as if it were an array. Finally, the OP said they had a getter for the array.

Comment: THANKS! Which class do I import for getArray?

Comment: @user14900 If your `Grid` class has a getter for the backing array, substitute that for `getArray()`. If it doesn't , you need to tell use how you access elements of the grid.

Comment: I assign values of it from a different class.

Comment: What are the methods in the `Grid` class that either 1) returns the backing array, or 2) sets/gets individual elements of the grid. Your question is not answerable without that information.

Comment: what do you mean by returns the backing array? (sorry still learning)

Comment: From your question it sounds like the `Grid` class makes use of an array internally. If there is a method that returns that array, that's what I'm referring to. If you don't provide us with more code, it is impossible to answer your question precisely. But, the answers that are here should give you an idea of what needs to be done anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you have access to all the data of the Grid object (i.e. getters and setters are available). Depending on the type of methods you have, your code could look like this for example.

```
public Grid copyGrid(Grid grid) {
    Grid g = new Grid(grid.getHeight(), grid.getWidth());

    for (int row = 0; row < height; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < width; col++) {
            g.setValue(row, col, grid.getValue(row, col));
    }
    return g;
}
```

Assuming that you can get and set individual values within the grid.

Comment: The question clearly mentions that the constructor cannot be modified and it's a 2d array, none of the methods work for 2d arrays.

Comment: @Kayaman - no it's not customary for down-votes to be explained.

Comment: Well, among the more civilized people it should be. I thought SO prided itself on quality.

Comment: @Kayaman Is that why you left a comment laced with F-bombs and then deleted it?

Comment: I never claimed to be civilized, yet I explain my downvotes. Besides, I didn't delete it, I was just trying to find out how it disappeared.